# How should punctuation be used in dialogues that end in "is all he/she/I said"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, dialogue

In dialogues that are like the following ones, should the comma follow the dialogues like it does in dialogues that end with "she/he/I said"?

"I'm coming home," she said. (Comma follows dialogue.)

But, what about dialogues like these:

"Don't go," is all he managed to say. Should it be "Don't go" is all he managed to say, or should the comma come in?

"That's how it is," is all she says. (Comma or not comma?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Don't go," is all he managed to say.*

is fine.

You could change it to
*"Don't go!" is all he managed to say.*

Take a look at this [blog post](http://theeditorsblog.net/2010/12/08/punctuation-in-dialogue/)